# How to submit data after validate.js by using php?

Tags: php, validate.js

I have a problem with submitting data with php after validate.js,  I have tried a lot but I have failed. please look at the code below.

Here is the example HTML form.

```
<form id="main" action="#/shd.php" class="form-horizontal" method="post" novalidate>
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="name" id="name" placeholder="Complete Name" required="">
                <div class="col-sm-10  messages"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" >Submit</button>
          </div>
```

Here are the last lines of code of validate

```
  <script>
   (function() {
  validate.extend(validate.validators.datetime, {       
    parse: function(value, options) {
      return +moment.utc(value);
    },
    // Input is a unix timestamp
    format: function(value, options) {
      var format = options.dateOnly ? "YYYY-MM-DD" : "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss";
      return moment.utc(value).format(format);
    }
  });

  // These are the constraints used to validate the form
  var constraints = {
    name: {
      presence: true,
      length: {
        minimum: 3,
        maximum: 20
      },
      format: {
        pattern: "[a-z0-9]+",
        flags: "i",
        message: "can only contain a-z and 0-9"
      }
    }
  };

  // Hook up the form so we can prevent it from being posted
  var form = document.querySelector("form#main");
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    handleFormSubmit(form);
  });

  // Hook up the inputs to validate on the fly
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select")
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    inputs.item(i).addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
      var errors = validate(form, constraints) || {};
      showErrorsForInput(this, errors[this.name])
    });
  }

  function handleFormSubmit(form, input) {
    // validate the form aainst the constraints
    var errors = validate(form, constraints);
    // then we update the form to reflect the results
    showErrors(form, errors || {});
    if (!errors) {
      showSuccess();
    }
  }

  // Updates the inputs with the validation errors
  function showErrors(form, errors) {
    // We loop through all the inputs and show the errors for that input
    _.each(form.querySelectorAll("input[name], select[name]"), function(input) {
      // Since the errors can be null if no errors were found we need to handle
      // that
      showErrorsForInput(input, errors && errors[input.name]);
    });
  }

  // Shows the errors for a specific input
  function showErrorsForInput(input, errors) {
    // This is the root of the input
    var formGroup = closestParent(input.parentNode, "form-group")
      // Find where the error messages will be insert into
      , messages = formGroup.querySelector(".messages");
    // First we remove any old messages and resets the classes
    resetFormGroup(formGroup);
    // If we have errors
    if (errors) {
      // we first mark the group has having errors
      formGroup.classList.add("has-error");
      // then we append all the errors
      _.each(errors, function(error) {
        addError(messages, error);
      });
    } else {
      // otherwise we simply mark it as success
      formGroup.classList.add("has-success");
    }
  }

  // Recusively finds the closest parent that has the specified class
  function closestParent(child, className) {
    if (!child || child == document) {
      return null;
    }
    if (child.classList.contains(className)) {
      return child;
    } else {
      return closestParent(child.parentNode, className);
    }
  }

  function resetFormGroup(formGroup) {
    // Remove the success and error classes
    formGroup.classList.remove("has-error");
    formGroup.classList.remove("has-success");
    // and remove any old messages
    _.each(formGroup.querySelectorAll(".help-block.error"), function(el) {
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    });
  }

  // Adds the specified error with the following markup
  // <p class="help-block error">[message]</p>
  function addError(messages, error) {
    var block = document.createElement("p");
    block.classList.add("help-block");
    block.classList.add("error");
    block.innerText = error;
    messages.appendChild(block);
  }

  function showSuccess() {
    // We made it \:D/
    alert("Success!");       
    return true;

  }
})();
</script>
```

When I click the Submit button after validating nothing happen!!, Anybody with experience with this validata.js code, please your idea.

Comment: don't use alert use console.log(). Then, you cad add _e.preventDefault()_ when you click on button submit. when you finish the validation you submit the form.

Comment: sorry @Sfili I can't get you please try to show me an example so that I can understand

Comment: i'll write you an answer so you can read better the code

Comment: Sorry @Sfill_81, I have posted all the codes. can you provide your answer from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do something like this

```
function submitForm( e ) {   
     e.preventDefault();
     //DO your validation stuff
     //if validation === TRUE
     $('#main').submit();// only this line was the solution.
};
```

So with `preventDefault` the default action of the event will not be triggered and when you click on the submit button you can do the validation before sending the data.

Comment: Sorry @Sfill_81, I have posted all the codes. can you provide your answer from there?

Comment: Have you check your browser console?